# limit of arctan

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve limit as x approaches 0 of $\tan ^{-1}(\frac{\sin(\pi +x)}{x}) $.

I looked up the answer and the answer is $-\frac{\pi}{4}$.

I've tried simplifying the terms inside the parentheses, but I can't get rid of the x in the denominator.

Here are a few things I have tried:

$\lim \frac{\sin(\pi + x)}{x}  = \lim \frac{\sin(x)cos(\pi)+sin(\pi)cos(x)}{x} = \lim \frac{\sin(x)\cos(\pi)}{x}+\frac{\sin(\pi)\cos(x)}{x} = (1)(-1) + \lim \frac{\sin(\pi)cos(x)}{x}$

but I still have that $x$ in the denominator.

If I could somehow get it as $\lim \frac{\sin(\pi + x)}{\pi+x} $ then I could make that limit 1, but I don't know how to do that.

Please help.

Comment: **Hint:** $\sin(\pi+x)=-\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin(\pi+x) = -\sin x$, we have
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{\sin x}{x}\right) 
    = \tan^{-1}\left(-\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\right)
    = \tan^{-1}(-1) = -\frac{\pi}{4}.$$
Interchanging the limit and $\tan^{-1}$ is valid since $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ exists and $\tan^{-1}$ is continuous at $1$.